# Disable notifications for chats but not calls when I set myself to a specific status in Skype

Tags: windows-7, skype

We use Skype, both chat and calls, a lot at work.  (NB: I run Windows 7.)

The problem is, sometimes I wish to concentrate on a particular task, and a big Skype chat is happening so it keeps bouncing at me even though I don't have much to add, so I want to disable the notifications for the chat messages.

However, if I set myself to "Do Not Disturb", it disables notifications of incoming calls as well (aside from an incredibly easy-to-miss flash in the Windows tray); if someone is calling me, they do actually want to talk to me specifically instead of "Anyone in the company who might happen to know the answer to x question".  So I need to keep receiving those.

Note: I actually want to *receive* the chat content, I just don't want my taskbar turning orange and opening the windows every time I close them.  "Reviewing them at my leisure" is sort of what I'm going for.

Is there some sort of happy medium for this?  Still all the bells and whistles for calls so I don't miss them, but chats behave as if I were set to "Do not disturb"?

Answer (score 1):

You can set IM notification settings per conversation on Skype for Windows by clicking on Conversation->Notification Settings... 
As of 5.7Beta you can give it a list of Keywords (such as your name) so that when someone asks a question to you specifically, you will still get a notification.